# How to add a clicklistener a cardview if some view overlay of cardview

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-cardview

this is my xml and I want to add a clicklistener to cardview but cardview clicklistener only work if I press vacant places left between nestedscroll view and card view. But I want to add a listener for cardview area, whatever clicked scrollview or textview not important. The area of the cardview on the screen is important to me. it is generally I am accuring, I am solving that problem with adding same clicklistener for all. maybe there will be cool way.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView_a"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cardView_b"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1">

            <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center">

                <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView_a"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:minHeight="75dp"
                        android:maxHeight="200dp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="18sp"
                        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="14sp"
                        app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
                        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />

                </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

            </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I faced this issue and hadovercome it by adding an image button with nullresource.

But why are you using such a complex layout I can't get. Why are you using a nested scroll view? And if you put a nestedscrollview, you can't transfer the click to the cardview.

Please state your requirement more specifically so we can answer that.

Comment: set `setPreventCornerOverlap(false)` where you have referenced your card view and let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can set a TouchListener on foreground components, then in their `onTouchEvent()` you can return `false` to indicate that touch event is not consumed. By this way the event will be passed step by step to background components to be managed by them.

I think there isn't a good solution for that situation

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

```
CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardView_a);
cardView .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("cardView","Card view clicked");

            }
        });`
```